# Determine on onclick whether the clicked link is meant to open a new window or tab

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tabs, click, target

Most modern browsers support the commands `ctrl+click` or `command+click` or similar to open links in a new tab or a new window.

In an application, I want the link to get disabled on clicking. But only, if the target is the same window (if it, for instance, opens in a new tab, I don't want the link to become disabled since it is reasonable to click it again).

I did some tries and debugged the event object that gets created on click - but I cannot find any information about whether the target is a new tab or a new window.

Known workaround: Certainly it is possible to check whether a certain key had been pressed while clicking a specific link, an easy thing - but since these commands vary from browser to browser and from OS to OS, one would have to define a complicated mapping and who nows exactly what the user has configured and so on.

Is there any reliable way of determining, whether the location should be opened in a new tab or window?

Answer (score 5):

Here you have a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pioul/eCuNU/4/

This script will allow the click on the link only if the link is going to open in a new tab/window, based on the `target="_blank"` attribute.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://google.fr" target="_blank">new window</a>
<a href="http://google.fr" target="_self">same window 1</a>
<a href="http://google.fr" target="">same window 2</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("a").bind("click", function(e){
    if($(this).attr("target") != "_blank"){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

You can take into account ctrl+clicks like this:

```
$("a").bind("click", function(e){
    if($(this).attr("target") != "_blank"){
        if(!e.ctrlKey){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, this only works with a fixed target attribute. If the user "overwrites" this by holding down ctrl (or similar), the attribute will not change of course and the determination therefore fails.

Comment: I edited my answer to match the case you talked about, and i guess there is no other solution than to think about every way a user could open a link in a new window and try to detect it within your code.

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is set by the browser settings to open links in new tab or in the same window.

You can check the target attribute of the link object.

```
<a href="http://your_link_to_page" target="_blank" >This open in new window</a>
```

Use javascript to manipulate the anchor tags at the page load and check for the target attributes. If the target value is set to _blank then enable them or you can perform this check when user clicks the link.

You can use a mechanism to find the CTRL is pressed when the link is clicked. There are some resources like [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/ctrl_alt.htm#properties). You can build a system.

NOte: if you are using JQuery use different classes to categorize links that have to be checked. And disable them on ready state or at time the links are clicked.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still does not apply if the user forces a new tab by holding down `ctrl`, does it?

Comment: You have to detect first what keys are pressed when the mouse down event occurred. This check has to be done in global scope (ie, in page scope). set a jS variable based on the key press. Then do the rest of checking inside the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent a browser to open a link in a new tab or window. There might be (undetecteable) configuration settings which force that, or think about mouse gestures: Right klick and moving down will open a new tab in Opera, and I guess this is undetectable.

Also, forcing a browser to open a tab in a new window (`target="_blank"` or even `window.open`) is considered bad style. You should let the user choose what he wants to do. If you really want to do, you also might consider `window.onunload` which should be working most times.

Comment: Well, it is not about preventing or forcing anything at all - it's about **detecting** whether the link will open in a new window or not - that's all.