# Suppress click event listener if the click opens a new tab or window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Sometimes on my web app I'd like to suppress the click event listeners if the click is supposed to open a new window or tab. For example, my single page application features links to another content. They work great, but there's one issue. If user clicks on such link, making a special click to open a new tab/window (let's say <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + click on Mac), I don't want to fire the event listener.

Normally I would do this:

```
<a href="/music">Music</a>
<a href="/games">Games</a>
<a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

And some jQuery magic:

```
$("a[href]").click(event => {
    if (event.metaKey || event.shiftKey) {
        // Let browser handle that normally if cmd or shift is pressed
        return true;
    }

    let uri = $(event.target).attr("href");

    // My viewPage(uri) function displays content by href
    viewPage(uri);

    return false;
});
```

It works as expected - whenever the mouse + keyboard shortcut has been used to open new tab/window, the current tab is not affected and the new tab/window appears.

The problem here is that it's an assumption that <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + click or <kbd>shift</kbd> + click are actually the shortcuts. They can be different for different browsers and systems.

So here's the question I'd like to ask: is there any reliable way to detect tab/window opening request in JavaScript? I find this functionality rather important. At least important enough to care.

Comment: And how does it help? It's worse idea than what I already got.

Comment: Look at http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: You can find interesting remarks in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8343742/1009922). Probably not the solution that you are looking for however.

Comment: @bigless This is not the answer to my question. I know how to read the keys. The question is if there's some special event triggered or other technique to catch the window/tab about to be opened. I don't think keeping track of all shortcuts in all browsers and all systems is the best idea, especially that some browsers may allow changing the shortcut button.

Comment: @bigless Yea, it wasnt answer. It was comment. You can see there that metaKey, ctrlKey etc are assigned differently according to system/browser. Can you mention any case(browser/OS) where it does not work?

Comment: No and I'm not interested in checking this. Assuming that it works is wrong, even if it works everywhere **at the moment**.

Comment: @ConnorsFan this other question is very similar, but it's old and the answers are irrelevant.

Comment: I thought that [Bergi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344220/1009922) regarding the possibility of opening a new window or tab with the context menu was relevant (giving you one more reason for not relying on key detection).

Comment: @ConnorsFan I edited question a little to make it more clear. I don't want to suppress new tab opening, but my custom action. So in my case I don't need to worry about context menu, because it works perfectly as it is - it doesn't trigger my custom action, as it's not even a left button click. Having a link clicked with cmd or shift (or whatever the browser wants us to press to open a new window/tab) is another story and that's the problem.

Comment: If you want full control, you must event.preventDefault() every click(left/right), no matter if key was pressed and handle it by yourself..

Comment: @bigless I don't think you understand the topic. What does the right click have to do with it?

Comment: @RoboRobok Maybe you can open link to tab/window from right-click contextmenu? I thought you want prevent opening links to tab/new window..

Comment: @bigless Yes, I can, but how is it relevant to my question? Please take a look at my comment to ConnorsFan, the one starting from "I edited question...".

Comment: @RoboRobok - I never thought that you wanted to suppress any navigation. But you are right that the context menu doesn't come into play because, as far as I can see, it doesn't have a command for normal navigation.

Comment: @ConnorsFan That wouldn't be terrible anyway. I would just end up with reloading the page. But without new window/tab detection, I end up with two tabs showing the same content, which is useless. This cmd/shift trick I made helps, but it doesn't make me sleep peacefully.

Comment: If you keep your current code, you will have to add `event.ctrlKey` (on Windows, it opens a new tab in Chrome, Firefox and Opera).

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yeah, I believe that's true. Anyway, I wonder if there's a fancier way or at least some feature not yet implemented. I really appreciate single page apps that still carry all these small comforts. It's annoying when a fancy-looking single page app doesn't allow you to open a content in new tab. I consider this a faulty web design.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make them anchors. Make them spans, and use the click event of the spans to set window.location. That would be a lot easier than finding every edge case where somebody wants to open content in a new window -- for example, right-click the link, copy link location, open a new tab/window, and pasting? You'll never be able to prevent that with anchor tags.

Comment: I don't want to **prevent** opening a new window. Quite the opposite. Actually, I hate it when bad single page applications disable many of the useful web browser features like bookmarking, opening new tabs, proper history browsing etc.

Comment: "Sometimes on my web app I'd like to supress the click event if this click was supposed to open a new window or tab." Sounded like preventing opening a new window to me. I'll look at this later; gotta run.

Comment: I mean to suppress the custom event and allow the default one in this case. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Well, I understand your concern, but I don't see a better approach to this. Responding to an unload event for the page would've done the trick years ago, but that's been sandboxed to all heck now, and there's no mechanism in the DOM to see if a link is opening locally or in a new tab/window. I would add a check for event.ctrlKey, as that tends to open in a new tab rather than a new page in Windows browsers.